# Firebase is not saving values from android device

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save to Firebase via Android. I am "connected" as it says in my android studio and I have downloaded the google-services.json file from Firebase. Please see the code below on how I implement it.

```
final Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.set_amount(Double.parseDouble(textView_receiptTotal.getText().toString().replace("PHP", "").trim()));
transaction.set_conductor(textView_conductorName.getText().toString());
transaction.set_destination(selectedRoutePostDestination.get_routePostCode());
transaction.set_distance(Integer.parseInt(selectedRoutePostDestination.get_routePostDistance()));
transaction.set_origin(currentPost.get_routePostCode());
transaction.set_passenger(Integer.parseInt(textView_receiptPassengers.getText().toString()));
transaction.set_type(selectedTransactionType);
transaction.set_vehicle(textView_vehicle.getText().toString());

ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().executeTask(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("transactions");
        mDatabaseReference.setValue(transaction);
        Log.e("log", "SOMETHING");
    }
});
```

**This is my project gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is my app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jiebao.demos"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        beta {
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        repositories { maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I don't get any errors. It just won't save.

Comment: You're not getting any errors because you're not checking for errors.  If you read the API documentation for setValue, you'll see it immediately returns a Task that tracks the asynchronous operation.  Use that task to figure out if there was a failure. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thank you so  much Sir. As usual, you're the man!